For any given positive definite matrix, can we find a corresponding coordinate transformation?
Suppose that $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a simply connected domain with $C^\infty$ boundary (for example a unit ball), and $A=A(x)$, $x\in\Omega$, is a $3\times 3$ positive definite matrix (may be not symmetric), such that
\begin{equation}
C^{-1}|\xi|^2\leq \xi^\top\cdot A\cdot\xi\leq C |\xi|^2,
\end{equation}
for some $C> 1$, all $\xi\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and all $x\in\Omega$. My question is: can we find a coordinate transformation $x=F(y)$ with $F: \tilde\Omega \to \Omega$ for some $\tilde \Omega$ where $y$ is defined, such that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial F^i}{\partial y^j}(y)=A^i_j(F(y)) \ \ \text{for }y\in \tilde\Omega?
\end{equation}

The metric of a coordinate transformation is symmetric naturally by $$J=\frac{\partial (x,y, \dots)}{\partial(\xi,\eta,\dots)}, \quad  G= J^T J.$$ Of course,  the matrix need not to be symmetric, e.g. an upper trigdiagonal with the same bilinear form will do. Reversed: any positive matrix symmetrized defines a Riemann manifold. The question is, if the manifold is flat. Thats the case if the Riemann curvature tensor is zero.
Zero curvature condition is equivalent to the symmetry of the second derivatives of a coordinate transformation $\mathbf X =\mathbf F(\mathbf Y )$
$$\partial_{y_i,y_k}\mathbf F(\mathbf Y)-\partial_{y_k,y_i}\mathbf F(\mathbf Y)=0$$
This fact is easy to show by the fundamental fact, that for a symmetric covariant derivative $\nabla$ the curl has no Christoffel terms
$$\nabla \mathbf u = \partial \mathbf u + \Gamma \mathbf u,  \quad \nabla \times \mathbf u = \partial \times \mathbf u$$
by combination of symmetric $\Gamma$ with antisymmetric $\times$
